# How to position a button based on the based on background of container?

Tags: html, css

I cant figure out how to position a button to always be locked at the bottom of the container no matter how much text is above it, at the moment it is positioned below the last p tag.

here is the page for more context.
the button is the "change read status".

https://repl.it/repls/AmusingLuxuriousColdfusion#index.html

Comment: Welcome to SO, your question is unclear, kindly describe your question in more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `position` to relative of your card div and then change the button position to `absolute` and `bottom: 0`

I have edited it in the repl for you.

https://repl.it/join/epzcgyjb-t2drink

Comment: No problem! Glad i could help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `position: absolute` property in your CSS since you are working within a `div`.

```
.[your button class] {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

What this does is it makes the position of your button relative to the container (i.e. the button's x and y coordinates will be based on the borders of the container). Then, you can use `top`, `bottom`, `right`, or `left` to position your element exactly where you want it to be. In this case, we just need `bottom` since you want to position it at the end.

Usually, elements are positioned based on `position: static`. There is also another property of `position: relative`, places an element relative to its current position without changing the layout around it. You can read more about the difference between `position: absolute` and `position: relative` [here](https://medium.com/@leannezhang/difference-between-css-position-absolute-versus-relative-35f064384c6#:%7E:text=position%3A%20relative%20places%20an%20element,changing%20the%20layout%20around%20it.).

Comment: Your answer makes the button shift to the bottom of the page because of not adding position relative to the containing card.